# Cannot access the .well-known/openid-configuration on IIS in production environment IdentityServer4

Tags: http-status-code-404, identityserver4, discovery

Company firewall is blocking the discovery document endpoint bc it contains "/." (".well-known/openid-configuration"). The firewall is blocking uri's with period following forward slash.

Is there an api available for overriding the discovery endpoint?

Error:
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https://xxx.xxx.com/identityserver/.well-known/openid-configuration

[Screnshot of firewall block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7qOS.png)